# Deploy Laravel on a local network

Tags: git, laravel, deployment

I have created a Laravel project in my ubuntu system. My client is using windows and other systems connected in network. How do i Deploy my app onto that local network and run it. Can I copy-paste my files on to wamp.

Comment: That should indeed be possible.

Comment: I have another doubt. If i paste it in 'pro-name' folder will the project run as 'localhost/pro-name' or i should do some other setting for it. or Is there a way to create a desktop icon for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that should work, just make sure you don't miss editing your database configuration on `app/config/database.php`.

In some situations, you may find that you need to move some folders around (`/app` and `public`) folder around, just remember that:

- the file `public/index.php` is the file that is served for all requests (except for images, css...), make sure your URL points to it.
- your stuff is on `/app`

So if you change the default folders structure, you will definitely need to check these two files: (1) `public/index.php` and (2) `bootstrap/paths.php`.

Comment: I have another doubt. If i paste it in 'pro-name' folder will the project run as 'localhost/pro-name' or i should do some other setting for it. or Is there a way to create a desktop icon for it.

Comment: but if i run `localhost/pro-name/public/index.php` it gives blank screen

Comment: @DevAbel This shouldn't be a problem, I believe you don't need to change anything.

Comment: Its working. I have frontend angularJs so some paths were messed up. thank you

Comment: i get this error `http://localhost/css/bootstrap.min.css` but these files are in public folder.